# Rsync include folder content but exclude parent folder

Tags: linux, rsync

I have scoured the web to no avail searching for an answer...
I'm trying to achieve this result at destination

```
Media_Files
    Web
        Print
```

My source files are

```
Media_Files
    Assets
        Web
            Print
```

How can I exclude, delete, remove or filter the `Assets` folder but keep the `Web/Print` folders using `rsync`? Thanks

Comment: I fixed the markup of the folder layout. Please correct it if I got it wrong.

Comment: The markup seems correct. I am trying the different solutions, but so far I'm unable to achieve what I want. I will post my results after thanksgiving.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to do this in two steps:

1. Copy everything except `Media_Files/Assets` (assuming there are other things under `Media_Files`).
2. Copy `Media_Files/Assets/Web`.

The first step can be done with

```
rsync -av --exclude=/Assets/ Media_Files/ destination
```

This would (verbosely) copy the `Madia_Files` directory recursively (including permissions and other meta-data) to `destination`, making `destination` a copy of `Media_Files` (remove the trailing `/` on the source path to instead create `destination/Media_Files`).

The `Assets` directory directly under `Media_Files` would be ignored due to the exclusion pattern `/Assets/`.

The second step can be done by

```
rysync -av Media_Files/Assets/Web destination
```

The lack of `/` at the end of the source path means that `Web` will be put inside `destination`.

If you have other files or directories in `Media_Files/Assets` apart from `Web` that you also need to copy, use instead

```
rsync -av Media_Files/Assets/ destination
```

This would copy everything from `Media_Files/Assets` (including the `Web` directory and its contents) directly into `destination`.

---

You could instead do the following two steps:

1. Make `destination` an *exact* copy of `Media_Files`, including `Media_Files/Assets`.
2. Manually move the contents of `destination/Assets` that you'd want to move into `destination` and delete `destination/Assets`.

In short:

```
rsync -av Media_Files/ destination
mv -i destination/Assets/* destination
rmdir destination/Assets
```

The last two commands would be modified to move only the contents of `destination/Assets` that you'd want to keep (e.g. `destination/Assets/Web`), and to remove the rest (here I'm assuming you'd want to move all visible files and directories, and that this leaves the `Assets` subdirectory completely empty).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to achieve the result

> rsync -azvP Media_Files/Assets/Web Media_Files/

Comment: We don't know whether there are files in `Media_Files` besides the `Assets` directory that needs copying, or in `Media_Files/Assets` for that matter. As far as we know, the user just wants to create a copy where `Media_Files/Assets/Web` (and possibly other contents of the `Assets` subdirectory) is moved up one level.